# PHP, Ajax, Java Table Update Form

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've attempted to alter, relocate, and redid these few lines for my application, however, the same error keeps popping up. It's an update to a database clause and it is correctly pulling the line information, inputting them into the form to edit, and displaying properly. However, when attempting to update it's throwing this error.

**Error Code**

> PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in  on line 49

Seemed simple enough to locate, and I understand what it's meaning. It's the **);** (**<------- Error Line** i wrote in the second set of code.)  which is closing the execute function. From the new input, everything is working fine with no issues and no errors displayed, however, this isn't working. I've even returned to the originator of the code to see if they could help, but no answer.

Please help, it's the last part I'm stuck on in order to finish this.

Main Page Code (Works fine as far as I can tell. Info is pulled, and correct)

```
$(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id");
$.ajax({
url:"fetch_single.php",
method:"POST",
data:{id:id},
dataType:"json",
success:function(data)
{
$('#userModal').modal('show');
$('#cust_firstname').val(data.cust_firstname);
$('#cust_lastname').val(data.cust_lastname);
$('#cust_address').val(data.cust_address);
$('#cust_city').val(data.cust_city);
$('#cust_state').val(data.cust_state);
$('#cust_zipcode').val(data.cust_zipcode);
$('#cust_tx').val(data.cust_tx);
$('#cust_email').val(data.cust_email);
$('.modal-title').text("Edit User");
$('#id').val(id);
$('#action').val("Edit");
$('#operation').val("Edit");
}
 })
});
```

Here's where my error is popping up

```
if($_POST["operation"] == "Edit")
{

 $statement = $connection->prepare(
"UPDATE customer 
 SET cust_firstname = :cust_firstname, cust_lastname = :cust_lastname, 
 cust_address = :cust_address, cust_city = :cust_city, cust_state = 
 :cust_state, cust_zipcode = :cust_zipcode, cust_email = :cust_email 
 WHERE id = :id
 "
 );
 $result = $statement->execute(
  array(
 ':cust_firstname' => $_POST["cust_firstname"],
':cust_lastname' => $_POST["cust_lastname"],
':cust_address' => $_POST["cust_address"],
':cust_city' => $_POST["cust_city"],
':cust_state' => $_POST["cust_state"],
':cust_zipcode' => $_POST["cust_zipcode"],
':cust_tx' => $_POST["cust_tx"],
':cust_email' => $_POST["cust_email"],
)
);  **<----- ERROR LINE**
if(!empty($result))
{
 echo 'Data Updated';
}
else {
 echo 'Error: Data not updated';
 }

 }
 }

 ?>
```

**Error Code**

> PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /home/r3home/public_html/mpitsolutions.info/db/customer/insert.php on line 49

Comment: You don't have any `cust_tx` in your update SQL and you don't have any `:id` in your execute array.

Comment: [Please do not tag multiple languages in your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354931/when-is-it-appropriate-to-tag-multiple-languages-in-my-question/) unless your question is specifically about these languages.  You may think it will lead to a faster answer, but the reality is that it is more likely to lead to a faster closure.

Comment: You should indent your code properly. That will help both you and us to follow the flow and find potential issues/errors.

Comment: Never post your website, especially when it's under development, and don't forget to authenticate users. Someone might try to hack it one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding more parameters that you have in the prepeared query. Specifically the line:

```
':cust_tx' => $_POST["cust_tx"],
```

dont exist in the prepeard query. So remove this line from where the query is executed, or add cust_tx it to the prepeared query.

In addition to this, as  Magnus Eriksson is pointing out, you also need to add the :id - parameter, which is defined in the prepeared statement.

Comment: There's one more issue. The OP has the parameter `:id` in the query but aren't adding that in the `execute()`.